# The instance of entity type '' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '' is already being tracked

Tags: c#

The exact error I am facing is 'The instance of entity type 'FeaturePreference' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{OrganizationId: 1, FeatureKey: TEST1}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.'

I am getting this error while using the Remove method

The error I am facing is while using the Remove method in the below code

```
public async Task<ResponseModel> DeletePMCLevelFeature(FeatureDetail featureDetails)
 {
            var responseCode = ResponseCodes.NotFound;
            var feature = await _amenityContext.FeaturePreferences.SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.FeatureKey == featureDetails.FeatureKey && p.OrganizationId == featureDetails.OrganizationId);
            if (feature != null)
            {
                _amenityContext.FeaturePreferences.Remove(feature);
                await _amenityContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                responseCode = ResponseCodes.Ok;
                return new ResponseModel() { ResponseCode = (int)responseCode, Model = "Feature Deleted at PMC Level Successfully", ErrorResponseModel = new ErrorModel() };
            }
            return new ResponseModel() { ResponseCode = (int)responseCode,  ErrorResponseModel = "Feature details not found" };
  }
```

The primary key is composite using FeatureKey and OrganizationID columns

I am getting this error while running the Unit Test cases for Delete Feature

In the constructor I am using the below code

```
public FeatureManager(AmenityContext context, AmenitySettings settings, IConfiguration configuration)
{
     _amenityContext = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
     _settings = settings ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(settings));
     _configuration = configuration; 
}
```

I am using the below AddDbContext in the ConfigureServices

```
services.AddDbContext<AmenityContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(SqlConnectionString,
                    sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
                    {
                        sqlOptions.CommandTimeout((int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(commandTimeoutMinutes).TotalSeconds);
                        sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name);
                        // Configuring Connection Resiliency: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-resiliency 
                        sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(maxRetryCount: 10, maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), errorNumbersToAdd: null);
                });
#if DEBUG
                options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);
                options.EnableDetailedErrors(true);
#endif
                // Changing default behavior when client evaluation occurs to throw.
                // Default in EF Core would be to log a warning when client evaluation is performed.
                options.ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning));
                // Check Client vs. Server evaluations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval
            });
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Are you caching the Context ? are you injecting it as scoped or a singleton ? what are you doing before calling `DeletePMCLevelFeature`

Comment: What is `AmenityContext`?

Comment: Before calling the DeletePMCLevelFeature feature, in the constructor of the controller we are using the below code. The constructor of the manager class is initiated. Not injecting as Scoped or Singleton  

 _featureManager = new FeatureManager(_amenityContext, _settings, _configuration);

Comment: AmenityContext is inheriting from DBContext and  is a class consisting of all the DBSets

Comment: You get this error if you have a stale Context around that has been used for another operation on the same entity. How are you adding your DbContext to the service collection? `AddDbContext`?

Comment: Added the DbContext service in the question

Comment: It can be hard to track down errors like this since it depends on what you're doing with the context earlier. Try putting a watch on `context.ChangeTracker.DebugView.ShortView` and you'll see all the tracked entities. From this perhaps you can discover when & why the change tracker already has a reference to a different object with the same key values.